# provoke slider's slide event jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to manually provoke jQueryUI slider's slide event in code?

```
$("#myslider").slide(100); //changes slider value to 100 and provokes sliders slide event
```

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833396/jquery-ui-slider-setting-programatically

Answer (score 0):

```
var slider = $('#myslider').slider();
slider.slider( "value", 100 );
```

This link might help you http://jqueryui.com/slider/#hotelrooms

Comment: As far as I tested this only invokes change method, not slide. Am I wrong?