# Jquery slider: move 2 sliders at the same time

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the same actions on multiple JQuery sliders.

I'm able to change the value input at the same time, but not the button of the slider.

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider(
    {
      min: 3,
      max: 30,
      step: 1,
      value: 10,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
      $( ".input" ).val( ui.value);
      }
    }
    );
  });
```

```css
.slider
{
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div class="slider"> </div>
<div> <input type="text" class="input" readonly value="0"/> </div>

<div class="slider"> </div>
<div> <input type="text" class="input" readonly value="0"/> </div>
```

Comment: its answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833396/jquery-ui-slider-setting-programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
      min: 3,
      max: 30,
      step: 1,
      value: 10,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
         $( ".input" ).val( ui.value);
         $(".slider").slider("value" , ui.value);
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.slider{
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<div class="slider"> </div>
<div> <input type="text" class="input" readonly value="0"/> </div>

<div class="slider"> </div>
<div> <input type="text" class="input" readonly value="0"/> </div>
```