# Setting jquery mobile sliders leads to error

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to set the value of a slider in jQuery mobile  1.4.5, JQ 2.1.4 and do get this error:

> Error: no such method 'values' for slider widget instance

HTML Code:

```
<div data-role="rangeslider" id="filter_price" style="touch-action: none;">
    <input type="range" name="price_from" id="price_from" min="0" max="30000" step="250"  data-popup-enabled="true">
    <input type="range" name="price_to" id="price_to" min="0" max="30000" step="250"  data-popup-enabled="true">
</div>
```

jquery:

```
   $('#filter_price').slider();
   $('#filter_price').slider('values', 0,  50);  
   $('#filter_price').slider('values', 1,  100);
```

This looks exactly like in [the answer provided on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833396/jquery-ui-slider-setting-programmatically) a few years ago, but might be outdated as it is from 8 years old.

Comment: While the accepted answer is referring to [jQuery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) Your question is clearly about [jQuery Mobile 1.4.5](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/rangeslider/). Be aware, these are two different libraries with different `rangeslider` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems here. Firstly you've created some `range` inputs inside the `div` you're instantiating the slider on. This is only going to cause problems as they interfere with the slider layout. I'd suggest removing them.

Secondly, calling `values` with two arguments is intended to be used with a range slider, not a single value slider. I would assume from the two range inputs you had in the DOM you're attempting to make this a range selection. As such you need to set `range: true` on the slider when you create it. Then you can call `values` as you currently are. Try this:

```js
$('#filter_price').slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 150
});
$('#filter_price').slider('values', 0, 50);
$('#filter_price').slider('values', 1, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div data-role="rangeslider" id="filter_price" style="touch-action: none;">
</div>
```

Also note that if you're attempting to create the slider with these values you can provide all arguments in the instantiation object, without needing to select the element again:

```js
$('#filter_price').slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 150,
  values: [50, 100]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<div data-role="rangeslider" id="filter_price" style="touch-action: none;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit too late to the party, but here is the solution for the jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 `rangeslider` (**not jQuery-UI**).

As the JQM `rangeslider` is effectively built on top of two JQM sliders, You can programmatically set the `min` and `max` values inside these two `create` events:

```js
var range = {
  "low": {min: 1, max: 10000}, 
  "medium": {min: 10000, max: 20000}, 
  "high": {min: 20000, max: 30000}
};

$(document).on("slidecreate", "#price_from", function(e) {
  $(this).val(range["medium"].min);
});

$(document).on("slidecreate", "#price_to", function(e) {
  $(this).val(range["medium"].max);
});

$(document).on("rangeslidercreate", "#filter_price", function(e) {
  // rangeslider has been created
});

$(document).on("change", "input:radio[name='price-range']", function() {
  $("#price_from").val(range[this.value].min);
  $("#price_to").val(range[this.value].max);
  $("#filter_price").rangeslider("refresh");
});
```

```css
.ui-slider-popup {
  width: auto !important;
  padding: 14px 8px 0 !important;
}

.ui-grid-a .ui-block-a,
.ui-grid-a .ui-block-b {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-one" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h3>Header</h3>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <br>
      <div class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
          <div data-role="rangeslider" id="filter_price" style="touch-action: none;">
            <input type="range" name="price_from" id="price_from" min="0" max="30000" step="250"  data-popup-enabled="true">
            <input type="range" name="price_to" id="price_to" min="0" max="30000" step="250"  data-popup-enabled="true">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
            <input name="price-range" id="price-range-low" value="low" type="radio">
            <label for="price-range-low">Low</label>
            <input name="price-range" id="price-range-medium" value="medium" type="radio" checked="checked">
            <label for="price-range-medium">Medium</label>
            <input name="price-range" id="price-range-high" value="high" type="radio">
            <label for="price-range-high">High</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```